# Show only an event based on select in angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

So I have a list of events that I want to be able to filter based on which state the event is in. I am creating the select as so:

```
    <select name="event-state" ng-model="stateChosen" class="form-control" ng-options="state.stateName for state in states" ng-change="stateChanged(stateChosen)"></select>
```

Here is the code in the controller that I am trying but I am not sure where to proceed from here.

```
    $scope.stateChanged = function(selectedState){
                    var selectedStates = selectedState.stateName.toLowerCase();
                    showFilteredStates(selectedStates,$scope.eventsList);
                };
                var showFilteredStates = function(states, allStates){
                    for(var i = 0;i < allStates.length; i++){
                        if(states === allStates[i].state){
                            ??Now what??
                        }
                    }
                };
```

Lastly here is the model that I have. Any ideas on where to go from here.

```
    $scope.eventsList = [
          {
            title: 'Event 1',
            type: 'warning',
            state: "california",
            starts_at: new Date(currentYear,currentMonth,25,8,30),
            ends_at: new Date(currentYear,currentMonth,25,9,30)
          },
          {
            title: 'Event 2',
            type: 'info',
            state: "california",
            starts_at: new Date(currentYear,currentMonth,25,7,30),
            ends_at: new Date(currentYear,currentMonth,25,9,30)
          },      {
            title: 'Event 4',
            type: 'info',
            state: "colorado",
            starts_at: new Date(currentYear,currentMonth,25,7,30),
            ends_at: new Date(currentYear,currentMonth,25,9,30)
          }
    ]
```

Comment: Your title says show only ONE object? So you only want to show one event, or you want to filter by a single state?

Comment: I only want to show one event. Would it be helpful if I changed the title to show one event?

Comment: So in the example, if I select California, which event do you want shown, because their are 2 for California. It seems your missing a part of your question, you clearly want to filter by state, but what decides which California. Do you want to paginate, just show one at a time and flip through?

Comment: If a user were to select california then I would want both californias to show. Its this event list could potentially get lots of states and we want the users to be able to show all the events for a specific state. Hopefully that helps

Comment: @ChadWatkins Can you please explain, how a data interchange format (JSON) is related to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do this, I can show you two. First, your missing your view (or at least you don't say where you want the filtered results to end up). This makes a difference on the answer.

Answer 1 of x....
This is a rudimentary example of putting the filtered events on the scope so they can be used in the view.

```
$scope.filteredStates = [];

$scope.stateChanged = function(selectedState){
    var selectedState = selectedState.stateName.toLowerCase();
    showFilteredStates(selectedState,$scope.eventsList);
};

var showFilteredStates = function(selectedState, events){
    var filteredStates = [];
    for(var i = 0;i < events.length; i++){
        if(selectedState === events[i].state){
            filteredStates.push(event[i]);
        }
    }
    // use this in your view
    $scope.filteredStates = filteredStates;
    return;
};
```

Answer 2 of x .....
This requires less work depending on your view. For this you can get rid of all that controller logic you currently have.

```
<select name="event-state" ng-model="stateChosen" class="form-control" ng-options="state.stateName for state in states" ng-change="stateChanged(stateChosen)"></select>

<div ng-repeat="event in eventsList | filter: {state:stateChosen.name} | limitTo:(page || 1)">
 {{event.name}}
</div>

<input type="text" ng-model="page">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-repeater` with  angular `filter` please see demo below, and if you want to show only one event add  use `limitTo:1`

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.eventsList = [{
    title: 'Event 1',
    type: 'warning',
    state: "california",

  }, {
    title: 'Event 2',
    type: 'info',
    state: "california",

  }, {
    title: 'Event 4',
    type: 'info',
    state: "colorado",

  }];



  $scope.states = [{
    name: "Alabama",
    abbreviation: "AL"
  }, {
    name: "Alaska",
    abbreviation: "AK"
  }, {
    name: "American Samoa",
    abbreviation: "AS"
  }, {
    name: "Arizona",
    abbreviation: "AZ"
  }, {
    name: "Arkansas",
    abbreviation: "AR"
  }, {
    name: "California",
    abbreviation: "CA"
  }, {
    name: "Colorado",
    abbreviation: "CO"
  }, {
    name: "Connecticut",
    abbreviation: "CT"
  }]
  $scope.stateChosen = $scope.states[4];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">

    <select name="event-state" ng-model="stateChosen" class="form-control" ng-options="state.name for state in states" ng-change="stateChanged(stateChosen)"></select>



    <div class="row" ng-repeat="event in eventsList | filter: {state:stateChosen.name} | limitTo:1">
      <h3>{{event.title}}<h3>
        <pre>{{event | json}} </pre>
      
      
    </div>
      </div>
</body>
```